# SQL UPDATE multiple rows at once after SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

My sample table:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| other_id   | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| another_id | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+------+----------+------------+
| id   | other_id | another_id |
+------+----------+------------+
|  988 |      102 |       NULL |
|  989 |      103 |       NULL |
|  990 |      104 |       NULL |
|  991 |      105 |       NULL |
|  992 |      106 |       NULL |
|  987 |      101 |       NULL |
+------+----------+------------+
```

How would I SELECT and UPDATE the above table in one query to the effect of doing something like this for every row:

```
UPDATE
    x
SET 
    another_id = 987
WHERE
    id = 987
    AND other_id = 101;
UPDATE
    x
SET 
    another_id = 988
WHERE
    id = 988
    AND other_id = 102
```

I would hate to run a manual update like this for every row and would like to do it all in one go.

Comment: Like it stands, it looks like you simply want to update `another_id` to the value of `id`?

Comment: Are you attempting to change the display order of items coming from the database? if so it can be done in a better way.

Comment: I don't see where SELECT comes into this problem!?!

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that you simply want to set the value of  `another_id` to `id`:

```
UPDATE
    x
SET 
    another_id = id
```

You can provide a range of `other_id` values in the where clause if you need to restrict the number of rows updated:

```
UPDATE
    x
SET 
    another_id = id
WHERE other_id IN (...) --list the values you want here.
```

Comment: If I have 1,000 records I would have to repeat that 1,000 times. I guess you could say I want to transfer the values in id column to another_id

Comment: No, you do not have to repeat the above update statement a 1000 times. The above statement will update all records in your table in one go unless you provide additional restrictions in the where clause.

Comment: Yes that is why I included the where in the example above. I don't just want to update all records to the same value. I want 988,987,990,991,etc to all be the same in another_id

Comment: Sort of like this UPDATE x set another_id = foo FROM (select * FROM x) WHERE some condition

Comment: Then just list them in the where clause using the in or the or operator or provide a range with the between ... and ... operator. I cannot specify a where clause for you unless you describe the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow is correct on his update statement.  It looks like you want to carry all ID directly into the ANOTHER_ID.  If you only want this to occur where the "Other_ID" is a given range, just add " where other_id between 101 and 21234" or whatever range you want it to happen for.

To see the results of what Shadow's answer would result in, change it to a simple SELECT statement to see.  If it is correct, change to the update version.  Example...

```
Select
      ID,
      ID AS Another_ID,
      Other_ID
   from
      YourTable
```

you will get all records showing the two columns showing the ID AS The "Another_ID".  It does NOT UPDATE The "Another_ID" column, just queries the value AS the result column name.  Again, if you wanted only certain range of numbers, just add

```
   where Other_ID between 101 and 21234
```

(or whatever value range)

Now, to see as an UPDATE command is exactly as Shadow TRIED to explain..

```
update YourTable set
      AnotherID = ID
```

and ALL records get updated...  If within specific range... use the same where clause as the Select.

If you want to try this without messing up production data, work with a temporary bogus table you can always delete after you are done..

```
insert into MyTempTable 
   ( ID, 
     Another_ID, 
     Other_ID 
   ) 
   select ID, Another_ID, Other_ID
      From YourTable
      where ID between 500 and 800
```

Now you have a test table to play with the insert table and see the impact...